# Blank maps updating google play services from 6.5 to 7.0

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I updated my google play services from 6.5.+ to 7.0.0
Maps worked well on previous version so avoid all questions about API key or store issues. I didn't change anything in my code, simply my gradle import and my manifest version (updated automatically).

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
```

Someone has some ideas of what happened? There's something new I need to implement?

**SOLVED**

It seems to be an issue with OpenStreetMap and google play services together, using normal maps v2 they work well. Actually i have still to solve the problem with OSM but this isn't related strictly to my question

Comment: is there any change in your package / signing key ?

Comment: just a guess that `google-play-services` on the phone need to be updated

Comment: @Atmaram Absolutely no

Comment: @Yurets i checked it now, they are updated to the last version

Comment: Are you using LocationClient for Map?

Comment: I'm using a library that needs google play services and maps, but i don't implement any methods, so actually i don't know it, it could influence on it? @DhavalPatel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with OpenStreetMap and google play services together, using normal maps v2 they work well.